# Zoom periodic incoming audio packet loss

Tags: networking, zoom-meeting

The symptom: On Zoom calls on a home LAN with around 6 people or more, every 3 minutes the incoming audio will drop out completely for about 5 seconds.  Zoom's inspection tool shows audio packet loss of nearly 100% during that span.  The video is always still fine and doesn't show any packet loss. Only the audio drops out, and it's **exactly 3 minutes apart**.  As in everything else is fine in the network, but every 3 minutes I'll get the issue.

My network path is:
`CAT 6 <-> switch <-> switch <-> Amplifi Router <-> Cable Modem in Bridge Mode <-> Xfinity with 300Mbps down and 10Mbps up.`

The issue occurs when I use the Zoom desktop client on my LAN.
It doesn't occur when I connect via the browser.
It doesn't occur when I use the desktop client and use my phone's hotspot.
I only have the issue in Zoom.
I've tried two computers on the same connection with the same symptoms.

I ran tests using https://packetlosstest.com/ while in a meeting, and even when Zoom was reporting an Internet connection issue and I experienced the audio dropout, packetlosstest showed no packet loss.

My next idea is to connect to the modem directly and let it route to remove the switches and Amplifi as possible culprits.

Any other suggestions on how to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Amplifi appears to be the culprit. I don't know why, but changing the cable modem to be the router and connecting via LAN cable to that solved the problem.